# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in React with Google charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a bit of a weird error with react and my google charts, when i first login to my page that shows my chart everything shows fine, but there's a place where i import data for new values to show on my chart and the chart disappears when i import new values and i get the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: processedData[(index + 1)] is undefined
```

This shows in the browser dev tools console, and when i run my debugger it shows this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
/src/components/Charts/DoubleColumnChart/DoubleColumnChart.js:48
The above error occurred in the <DoubleColumnChart> component:
    in DoubleColumnChart
```

The error seems to be in this part of my code:

```
      data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
    processedData[0].push(dataset.label);
    dataset.data.forEach(function (data, index) {
      processedData[index + 1].push(data);
    });
  });
```

I read some documentation on `withRouter` but i dont know if that would work here. Here is my full code:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

export const DoubleColumnChart = (props) => {

  const processData = (data) => {
    if (data == null) return [[]];
    if (data.labels == null) return [[]];
    var processedData = [[]];
    processedData[0].push('Category');
    data.labels.forEach(function (label) {
      var finalLabel = label[0];
      if (label.length > 1) {
        for (var i = 1; i < label.length; i++) {
          if (finalLabel.length > parseInt(160 / data.labels.length, 10)) {
            finalLabel = finalLabel + '...';
            break;
          }
          finalLabel = finalLabel + '\n' + label[i];
        }
      }
      processedData.push([finalLabel]);
    });
    console.log(data.datasets);
      data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
        processedData[0].push(dataset.label);
        dataset.data.forEach(function (data, index) {
          processedData[index + 1].push(data);
        });
      });


    return processedData;
  }

  const processColors = (data) => {
    if (data == null) return [];
    if (data.datasets == null) return [[]];
    var processedColors = [];
    data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
      processedColors.push(dataset.backgroundColor);
    });
    return processedColors
  }

  if (props.isVisible == false) {
    return <div></div>;
  }
  return (
    <Chart
      width={'99%'}
      height={'375px'}
      chartType="ColumnChart"
      loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
      data={processData(props.data)}
      options={{
        animation: {
          duration: 1500,
          easing: 'out',
          startup: true,
        },
        legend: { position: 'bottom', textStyle: { color: 'gray' } },
        vAxis: { textStyle: { color: 'gray' } },
        hAxis: { textStyle: { fontSize: 10, color: 'gray' } },
        tooltip: { trigger: 'hover', showColorCode: true },
        chartArea: {
          top: '2%',
          left: '5%',
          height: "77%",
          width: "100%",
        },
        colors: processColors(props.data),
        dataOpacity: '0.9',
      }}
      chartEvents={[
        {
          eventName: 'select',
          callback: ({ chartWrapper }) => {
            const chart = chartWrapper.getChart()
            const selection = chart.getSelection()
            if (selection.length === 1) {
              const [selectedItem] = selection;
              const { row } = selectedItem;
              var labelData = props.data.labels[row];
              var finalLabel = '';
              for (var i = 0; i < labelData.length; i++) {
                finalLabel = finalLabel + labelData[i];
              }
              finalLabel = finalLabel.replace(/ /g, '');
              if (props.onSegmentClick) props.onSegmentClick(finalLabel);
            }
          },
        },
      ]}
      rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
    />
  );
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are pushing data to an array with index+1 logic, so you should check that the next index of the array exists and then push data to that or convert the next index to an array and then push.
So, the typesafe way is something like this:

```
if(Array.isArray(processedData[index + 1])) {
    processedData[index + 1].push(data);
}else {
   processedData[index + 1] = [data]
}
```

Comment: Thank you that seemed to have worked, my chart shows, however i get the following error in console, how should i suppress this? `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row 6 has 2 columns, but must have 3`

Comment: As I understand, You have 3 columns instead of 2. check the length of your column and make sure you have 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript push method can be used on array.

For example:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.push("Kiwi");
```

But in the below method you are using   processedData[0].push(dataset.label) which is like acessing the first element of the array and pushing into it which is wrong. You can do like   processedData.push(dataset.label).

```
  data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
        processedData[0].push(dataset.label);
        dataset.data.forEach(function (data, index) {
          processedData[index + 1].push(data);
        });
```